# Tracking Multi-Index and Modifying Values in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, multi-index, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array that I am iterating over in an effort to use the index values to make calculations and then assign the calculated value to said index.

In the NumPy documentation, [an example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values) is provided for modifying values using an iterator:

```
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = 2 * x
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when tracking an index using [the following method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index):

```
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    it[...] = . . .
    it.iternext()
```

I am, however, able to use the `it.multi_index` values, but it seems unnecessarily verbose. Is there a simpler way to achieve this, either through a different approach or different syntax?

```
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    matrix[it.multi_index[0]][it.multi_index[1]] = . . .
    it.iternext()
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is an example of a `multi_index` iteration attempting to modify values using iterator indexing and failing.

```
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
it = np.nditer(matrix, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
  it[...] = 1
  it.iternext()
```

The error produced is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-3f4cabcbfde6> in <module>()
     25 it = np.nditer(matrix, flags=['multi_index'])
     26 while not it.finished:
---> 27   it[...] = 1
     28   it.iternext()

TypeError: invalid index type for iterator indexing
```

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" this kind of statements are better when followed by a [mcve]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first iteration example:

```
In [1]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [2]: for x in np.nditer(arr, op_flags=['readwrite']):
   ...:     print(x, type(x))
   ...:     x[...] = 2 * x
   ...:     
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
3 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
4 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
....
11 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
In [3]: x
Out[3]: array(22)
In [4]: arr
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
```

Turn on multi_index:

```
In [9]: it = np.nditer(arr, flags=['multi_index'],op_flags=['readwrite'])
In [10]: while not it.finished:
    ...:     print(it[0], it.multi_index)
    ...:     it.iternext()
    ...:     
0 (0, 0)
2 (0, 1)
4 (0, 2)
...
20 (2, 2)
22 (2, 3)
```

Same iteration through the elements of `arr`, but is also generates the 2d index tuple. `it` is the `nditer` object, with various methods and attributes.  In this case it has a `multi_index` attribute.  And the current iteration variable is in `it[0]`.

I can modify elements either with the `[...]` inplace, or by indexing in `arr`:

```
In [11]: it = np.nditer(arr, flags=['multi_index'],op_flags=['readwrite'])
In [13]: while not it.finished:
    ...:     it[0][...] *= 2
    ...:     arr[it.multi_index] += 100
    ...:     it.iternext()
    ...:     

In [14]: arr       # values are doubled and add by 100
Out[14]: 
array([[100, 104, 108, 112],
       [116, 120, 124, 128],
       [132, 136, 140, 144]])
```

Without `multi_index` I could still create an `nditer` object, and iterate with the `while not finished` syntax.  Instead of accessing `x[...]` I'd have to use `it[0][...]`.

---

`np.ndindex` is a more convenient way of generating a `multi_index`.  Look at its code.  It's one of the few numpy functions that uses `np.nditer`.

```
In [26]: for idx in np.ndindex(arr.shape):
    ...:     print(idx)
    ...:     arr[idx] -= 100
    ...:     
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
...
(2, 3)
In [27]: arr
Out[27]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8, 12],
       [16, 20, 24, 28],
       [32, 36, 40, 44]])
```

### But

While it is fun to play with `nditer`, it isn't practical, at least not in pure Python code.  It is most useful as a stepping stone toward using it in `cython` or pure `c` code.  See the final example of the iteration page.